# Android tab layout broken scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have a small problem with the tab layout. After I have implemented tab layout and put the recycle view in I have the problem that after I scroll the list the toolbar seem to blend with the title. Am I making the mistake in the code tab activity or its some other issue.

Thanks

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Tab activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_completed__challenges);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tab1_completed_running tab1 = new tab1_completed_running();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                tab2_completed_walking tab2 = new tab2_completed_walking();
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                tab3_completed_cycling tab3 = new tab3_completed_cycling();
                return tab3;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Running";
            case 1:
                return "Walking";
            case 2:
                return "Cycling";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Layout of recycle view:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/tab_resultList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

[image]

Comment: seems to me your RecyclerView is over the toolbar. Post your layouts

Comment: Please check updated post

Comment: Your first layout is incomplete, check that you're using `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: I do use the CoordinatorLayout , just did not paste that in post